# Correct way to deal with a case of POST method request Http4s

Tags: scala, http, post, http4s

I have a Post request sent over a network to get data related to a user
I'm using Http4s for this.

When writing the HttpRoutes I'm using this to handle the case of POST as follows:

```
case req @ POST -> Root/ "posts" { "name": username, "friends": friends} =>
```

the `name` and the `friends` are attributes passed as parameters in the body of the request.

Yet there is some syntax error I can seem to identify `'=>' expected but '{' found`.

Answer (score 7):

That's an incorrect Scala syntax.
Here's an example from the official [http4s docs](https://http4s.org/v0.21/json/):

```
 case req @ POST -> Root / "hello" / id =>
    for {
      // Decode a User request
      user <- req.as[User]
      // Encode a hello response
      resp <- Ok(Hello(user.name).asJson)
    } yield (resp)
```

You're accessing API at "/hello" route. Then the request is decoded (unmarshalled) to `User` instance. E.g. you can use Circe JSON library to decode a content from a request:

```
import io.circe.generic.auto._
import io.circe.syntax._

import org.http4s._
import org.http4s.circe._
```

`id` is a path variable. Here, you can take a look how to use query params too: https://http4s.org/v0.21/dsl.

Circe encoder is being used to convert `User` instance to JSON content for the response.

```
Ok(Hello(user.name).asJson)
```

Comment: I have already checked the documentation but I didn't understand it well,  in the doc there are no attributes passed as parameters  I cant still seem to get how to do it

Comment: @AM Parameters are in the body of the POST request.

Comment: Are you talking about the example I have posted in the question ? If yes It is an incorrect syntax

Comment: You want to access query parameters?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Yes, and secondly the correct way to write the  code as I'm getting incorrect syntax

Comment: @AM check the docs about query parameters and take a look to the scaladoc as well: https://http4s.org/v0.21/dsl/#handling-query-parameters

Comment: Thank you @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez